# how to receive and play RTP stream in vlc?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to play a RTP string using vlc media player. and the address for that is rtp://10.x.x.1:5114\video01

but whenever I use this address in vlc stream as rtp://@10.x.x.1:5114\video01 it generates the error VLC is not able to open the MRL

but the same was working for a multicast address like rtp://224.x.x.x:5004

Comment: Did you try `/` instead of ``\``?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tags. If it is a coding question then it is off-topic.

Comment: Yes, I have  tried /  but not working.

Comment: Ensure you are not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Try to define everything in an SDP file, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol. Than run vlc <file.sdp>